# Create If Next loop with multiple variables (working code)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I have a table that I use to dynamically adjust a chart.

For this I use the following code which works as intended but since I am new to VBA I have difficulties creating a loop here so that I don't have to list every single series / category.

**In total there are 8 series and 17 categories.**
- The series filters (true / false) are listed in "`B27:B34`",
- the category filters are listed in "`C25:S25`",
all on Worksheets(3).

Can someone help me with this ?

**My code (shortened):**

```
Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim varSeries1 As String
    Dim varSeries2 As String
    Dim varSeries3 As String
    ' ...
    Dim varCategory1 As String
    Dim varCategory2 As String
    Dim varCategory3 As String
    ' ...

    varSeries1 = Worksheets(3).Cells(27, 1).Value
    varSeries2 = Worksheets(3).Cells(28, 1).Value
    varSeries3 = Worksheets(3).Cells(29, 1).Value
    ' ...
    varCategory1 = Worksheets(3).Cells(25, 3).Value
    varCategory2 = Worksheets(3).Cells(25, 4).Value
    varCategory3 = Worksheets(3).Cells(25, 5).Value
    ' ...

    Worksheets(3).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered = varSeries1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = varSeries2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).IsFiltered = varSeries3
    ' ...
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(1).IsFiltered = varCategory1
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(2).IsFiltered = varCategory2
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(3).IsFiltered = varCategory3
    ' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays :

```
Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim arrSeries() As Boolean
    Dim arrCategory() As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    arrSeries = Worksheets(3).Range("B27:B34").Value
    arrCategory = Worksheets(3).Range("C25:S25").Value

    Worksheets(3).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

    For i = LBound(arrSeries, 1) To UBound(arrSeries, 1)
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = arrSeries(i, 1)
    Next i
    For i = LBound(arrCategory, 2) To UBound(arrCategory, 2)
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = arrCategory(1, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - this looks great but when I run it the debugger starts highlighting the ActiveChart... line in the first for loop. Run-time error 13 - type mismatch.

Comment: You might have to use `CBool(arrSeries(i, 1))` and `CBool(arrCategory(1, i))`

Comment: @VincentG: Thanks - I tried this with the first for line but then also get an error: Subscript out of range.

Comment: If FullSeriesCollection is zero-based, since the arrays are 1-based you will need to substract the LBound from i.

Comment: @VincentG : it seems to be 1-based too. Changed it to include typing as Boolean, let me know if that still doesn't work, you may have to include VincentG proposition too.

Comment: @R3uK: Thanks a lot - now I get the type mismatch error on the first line (arrSeries = ...).